# TQL How do I receive the max per column

Tags: sql, t-sql, select, max

This is my first post and I'm hoping someone can help.  My hope is that I can understand the logic before attempting to figure things out on my own.  The idea here is to show the specific notes from left to right (hence the LOJs, each LOJ is a different note), for each of those joins I would like to pull the max service date ultimately rolling up the data to one row for each person.  The code is below and I greatly appreciate the help.  Mostly self taught and I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2.  Also if the code is too much just let me know how it would help for me to condense it and I will do so.

```
SELECT dbo.tConTESTs.FirstName
    ,dbo.tConTESTs.LastName
    ,dbo.tConTESTs.MI
    ,dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    ,dbo.tConTESTs.SSN
    ,dbo.tConTESTOrganizations.OrganizationID
    ,dbo.tConTESTOrganizations.AdmitDate
    ,dbo.tConTESTOrganizations.DischargeDate
    ,ImprovementNote_1.ImprovementNoteID
    ,ImprovementNote_1.TemplateID
    ,ImprovementNote_1.ServiceDate
    ,ImprovementNote_2.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr1
    ,ImprovementNote_2.TemplateID AS Expr2
    ,ImprovementNote_2.ServiceDate AS Expr4
    ,ImprovementNote_3.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr5
    ,ImprovementNote_3.TemplateID AS Expr6
    ,ImprovementNote_3.ServiceDate AS Expr8
    ,ImprovementNote_4.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr9
    ,ImprovementNote_4.TemplateID AS Expr10
    ,ImprovementNote_4.ServiceDate AS Expr12
    ,ImprovementNote_5.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr13
    ,ImprovementNote_5.TemplateID AS Expr14
    ,ImprovementNote_5.ServiceDate AS Expr16
    ,ImprovementNote_6.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr17
    ,ImprovementNote_6.TemplateID AS Expr18
    ,ImprovementNote_6.ServiceDate AS Expr20
    ,ImprovementNote_7.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr21
    ,ImprovementNote_7.TemplateID AS Expr22
    ,ImprovementNote_7.ServiceDate AS Expr24
    ,ImprovementNote_8.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr25
    ,ImprovementNote_8.TemplateID AS Expr26
    ,ImprovementNote_8.ServiceDate AS Expr28
    ,ImprovementNote_9.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr29
    ,ImprovementNote_9.TemplateID AS Expr30
    ,ImprovementNote_9.ServiceDate AS Expr32
    ,ImprovementNote_10.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr33
    ,ImprovementNote_10.TemplateID AS Expr34
    ,ImprovementNote_10.ServiceDate AS Expr36
    ,ImprovementNote_11.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr37
    ,ImprovementNote_11.TemplateID AS Expr38
    ,ImprovementNote_11.ServiceDate AS Expr40
    ,ImprovementNote_13.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr45
    ,ImprovementNote_13.TemplateID AS Expr46
    ,ImprovementNote_13.ServiceDate AS Expr48
    ,ImprovementNote_14.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr49
    ,ImprovementNote_14.TemplateID AS Expr50
    ,ImprovementNote_14.ServiceDate AS Expr52
    ,ImprovementNote_15.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr53
    ,ImprovementNote_15.TemplateID AS Expr54
    ,ImprovementNote_15.ServiceDate AS Expr56
    ,ImprovementNote_16.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr57
    ,ImprovementNote_16.TemplateID AS Expr58
    ,ImprovementNote_16.ServiceDate AS Expr60
    ,ImprovementNote_17.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr61
    ,ImprovementNote_17.TemplateID AS Expr62
    ,ImprovementNote_17.ServiceDate AS Expr64
    ,ImprovementNote_18.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr65
    ,ImprovementNote_18.TemplateID AS Expr66
    ,ImprovementNote_18.ServiceDate AS Expr68
    ,ImprovementNote_19.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr69
    ,ImprovementNote_19.TemplateID AS Expr70
    ,ImprovementNote_19.ServiceDate AS Expr72
    ,ImprovementNote_20.ImprovementNoteID AS Expr73
    ,ImprovementNote_20.TemplateID AS Expr74
    ,ImprovementNote_20.ServiceDate AS Expr76
FROM dbo.tConTESTs
INNER JOIN dbo.tConTESTOrganizations ON dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTOrganizations.ConTESTID
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_1  
       ON ImprovementNote_1.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID  
      AND ImprovementNote_1.TemplateID = 10
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_2 ON ImprovementNote_2.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_2.TemplateID = 13
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_3 ON ImprovementNote_3.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_3.TemplateID = 12
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_4 ON ImprovementNote_4.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_4.TemplateID = 14
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_5 ON ImprovementNote_5.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_5.TemplateID = 49
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_6 ON ImprovementNote_6.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_6.TemplateID = 19
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_7 ON ImprovementNote_7.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_7.TemplateID = 24
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_8 ON ImprovementNote_8.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_8.TemplateID = 25
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_9 ON ImprovementNote_9.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_9.TemplateID = 26
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_10 ON ImprovementNote_10.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_10.TemplateID = 27
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_11 ON ImprovementNote_11.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_11.TemplateID = 36
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_13 ON ImprovementNote_13.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_13.TemplateID = 51
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_14 ON ImprovementNote_14.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_14.TemplateID = 6
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_15 ON ImprovementNote_15.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_15.TemplateID = 7
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_16 ON ImprovementNote_16.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_16.TemplateID = 8
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_17 ON ImprovementNote_17.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_17.TemplateID = 35
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_18 ON ImprovementNote_18.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_18.TemplateID = 18
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_19 ON ImprovementNote_19.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_19.TemplateID = 16
LEFT JOIN dbo.ImprovementNote AS ImprovementNote_20 ON ImprovementNote_20.ConTESTID = dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    AND ImprovementNote_20.TemplateID = 11
WHERE  dbo.tConTESTOrganizations.DischargeDate IS NULL
   AND dbo.tConTESTOrganizations.OrganizationID IN (2,3)
   AND dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID = 508
ORDER BY dbo.tConTESTs.LastName
```

Comment: Thank you for cleaning it up Siyual, much appreciated.

Comment: Suggestion 1: If your LOJ is specifying an exact TemplateID, then there's no need to retrieve that TemplateID in the select list.

Comment: Suggestion 2: Using column aliases like `Expression74` is a very bad idea -- it will never be maintainable. Since you're retrieving data for a specific templateID, how about using an alias that describes that templateID: like `ImprovementNoteID_template16`.

Comment: Ross, You're absolutely correct that the templateID is redundant and not needed, however due to some limitations of crystal reports I tend to utilize both date type and string data items when possible (it's a lot harder to add them after the fact if needed).  I will be cleaning up the expression names specific to the templateID and then displaying an "X" if they are there or not via crystal reports.  My plan is to do this after I'm assured the max can be done properly (I don't want to spend all that time specifying the expression if the max isn't going to work).

Comment: Did you really have to list 20 joins with identical syntax to ask the question?   On top of the terrible formatting.

Comment: Yes, I did.  I'm not looking for the full code to be written, I'm looking for an example of logic that will work with this type of query build.  I can do the work I just want to make sure its possible with this type of query structure...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dbo.tConTESTs.FirstName
    ,dbo.tConTESTs.LastName
    ,dbo.tConTESTs.MI
    ,dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
    ,dbo.tConTESTs.SSN
    ,dbo.tConTESTOrganizations.OrganizationID
    ,dbo.tConTESTOrganizations.AdmitDate
    ,dbo.tConTESTOrganizations.DischargeDate
    ,max(ImprovementNote_1.ServiceDate) as [ImprovementNote_1.ServiceDate.Max]  
....
group by dbo.tConTESTs.FirstName
        ,dbo.tConTESTs.LastName
        ,dbo.tConTESTs.MI
        ,dbo.tConTESTs.ConTESTID
        ,dbo.tConTESTs.SSN
        ,dbo.tConTESTOrganizations.OrganizationID
        ,dbo.tConTESTOrganizations.AdmitDate
        ,dbo.tConTESTOrganizations.DischargeDate
```

if you need the notes from the last date then need to use row_number() over